# How do I get event when backspace and length of TextInput = 0

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

This is my code React native:
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

```
const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("");
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default UselessTextInput;
```

Link expo: https://snack.expo.dev/@robocon321/textinput

Answer (score 1):

#### use [onKeyPress](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onkeypress)

```js
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
  if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
     alert("Backspace is pressed")
  } 
}}
```

try snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed_gaber/dfb099)

##### work on ios & android

##### note on android!

> Note: on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not the hardware keyboard inputs.

`soft keyboard` (*onscreen keyboard or software keyboard*) like keyboard in the screen of phone or tablet.
`hardware keyboard` (*external keyboard*) like keyboard with USB (android support that) but you can ignore it.